# Is there an Android running app which has a speed target, and MEASURES your speed, gives audio feedback?

Tags: android, sport

Is there an Android running app which has a speed target, and MEASURES your speed, gives audio feedback when falling below a set limit?

I am looking for something that doesn't require extra hardware. Phone's GPS capabilities etc. are adequate to measure speed.

Comment: You mean, audio feedback when exceeding the set limit? I'll bet one of the [Speedometer & HUDs](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_speedometer) apps does that. Especially, check the [Speed Limiter](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_speedometer#group_956) section ;)

Comment: I mean when falling below the set limit...