# Android app for interval training (lap running)

Tags: android, gps, sport

I am following a custom training plan for long runs. Basically I would like to have a GPS tracking app that allows to

1. Build a custom run, that is, a sequence of intervals (with duration specified by distance or time), along with a pace goal for each interval. For example: 2x 1600m @ 05:50/km, with 400m recovery (as slow as needed), followed by 800m @ 05:40/km.
2. Track your progress, giving you some audio feedback if you're too slow or too fast w.r.t. the desired pace during the current interval.
3. Display your results after the end of the run, showing in particular the total time for each interval.

I have used Runtastic (Pro) so far, but it does not meet these criteria. In fact, you can only set five non-overlapping "zones" for the pace, and they cannot be too narrow otherwise you would have audio feedback continuously (which I find distracting and useless); thus, the previous example cannot be done. More importantly, point n.3 is completely missed by Runtastic; you can only show your results by fixed lengths (either 500m or 5 minutes), no matter your intervals' lengths.

I already checked most of the other well-known apps (Nike, Adidas, RunKeeper…) but they all fail in some way. I am told by fellow runners with iPhones that iSmoothRun allows everything I need, but they do not seem to be planning an Android version. Do you know of any app meeting my criteria, no matter how obscure or expensive? Maybe in development, at least?

Comment: I'm not sure if the perfect app for this does exist (I'm lazy concerning sports ;) – but my list of [Fitness](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/sport_fitness) apps has some of the candidates you've mentioned and some more. Maybe take a look into while waiting for answers?

Comment: "they all fail in some way": Would you mind telling us how each one fails to meet your requirements? Thanks!

Comment: Related question (requesting feedback only when you're too slow): http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19246/is-there-an-android-running-app-which-has-a-speed-target-and-measures-your-spee